# Hg: [subpaths] section in .hgsub not able to accept other then lowercase names?

Tags: mercurial, subrepos

**Is it supposed to be possible to have case sensitive directory names containing mercurial subrepos?**

I'm creating thin shell repository UberRepo with 2 sub-repositories: `Foo` and `BaR`.

If I name the directories `foo`, `bar` (lowercase) and put following content in `.hgsub` file:

```
foo= foo
bar= bar

[subpaths]
https://bitbucket\.org/teamname/uberrepo/foo = https://bitbucket.org/teamname/foo
https://bitbucket\.org/teamname/uberrepo/bar = https://bitbucket.org/teamname/bar
```

Then everything (push, pull, clone) works like a charm. The problem is that the directories with subrepos are in lowercase.

If I name the directories `Foo`, `BaR` than no matter of what I put into `.hgsub` I always get same 404 error, because hg is trying to push to `https://bitbucket.org/teamname/uberrepo/Foo` - basically no replacement is taking place.

What can I do to keep the non-lower-case directory names while still being able to make hg understand my simple subrepo structure?

**Possible workaround:**
I have found that part of the problem might be that hg (based on hgrc settings) pushes username int o URL. It still does not answer why everything works fine with lowercase. But I have simply downloaded code of hg, searched the code responsible for replacements, fiddled around and found that this can be workarounded by usage of regex:

```
foo= foo
bar= bar

[subpaths]
^https://([^/]*)/teamname/uberrepo/([^/]*)$ = https://\1/teamname/\2
```

This solves the issue. Still it should not be needed and should be much easier than that in such simple case (as simple as just putting the exact url)